# How to create a list of one object attributes from the actual list of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have an ObservableCollection of object that I've define `Connection`.

How can I extract all URL from all connections in that list?

I want to do something like that but in the correct way:

```
ObservableCollection<Connection> connectionList;
List<string> listUrl = new List<string>();

foreach (var connection in connectionList)
{
    listUrl.Add(connection.PortalUrl);
}
```

Comment: why do you think this is incorrect ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> "in the correct way"

Well there's nothing "wrong" with your approach, but if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher it *could* be done in one line using Linq:

```
List<string> listUrl = connectionList.Select(c => c.PortalUrl).ToList();
```

If you don't understand how Linq works then stick with your method - they're functionally equivalent.

If you haven't used Linq in your project yet just add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the class file along with the other namespace imports

Comment: I don't have select on the ObservableCollection 

NVM!

Comment: @Cedric: have you imported `using System.Linq;`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Select`:

```
var urls = connectionList.Select(x => x.PortalUrl).ToList();
```

Since this is about as basic LINQ as you can get, I suggest you take a look at some examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you can use linQ "using system.Linq"

This should do the trick

`connectionList.Select(con => con.Url).ToList()`